# Can I replace the "Save" or "Save as" button with VBA Save function in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem about Save in Excel.

I got a VBA script code that can save file, but I wonder if I could just click "Save"/"Save as" button to trigger the script instead of create a new Label and add sub for that label.

Is that possible for me to do that?

Comment: Hi Wayne, it seems you already understand how to save a document using VBA. If so, your question is how to run the rest of your script every time somebody hits the normal save button? Did I understand the question correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run a script everytime the workbook is saved, you need to place code in the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event. You would place it in the ThisWorkbook module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox ("Hello World")
End Sub
```

This code will now run everytime the workbook is saved, regardless of how the command to save was executed. In my example it triggers a message box, but obviously, you can run any code you choose.

Comment: seem like it not work for me. Somehow when i tried save/save as, nothing happened

Comment: Did you place the code in `ThisWorkbook`? It will only work in that module, not a regular one!

Comment: yes, that worked. I edited the comment, and it haven't been updated yet. Thank you, alot